# Autodesk-Forge - How can I get all items with attributes from BIM360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to get all items with attributes from inside folder and sub-folders.

I am using below API but it is returning max 200 rows per call and max 50 page allowed

'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search'

Expecting below response...

```
{
     "type":"items",
     "id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:4O--hn0hQA-1Uqu222kjAQ",
     "attributes":{
        "displayName":"WT1-131-D0-A01.pdf",
        "createTime":"2022-08-01T21:28:02.0000000Z",
        "createUserId":"RBYHJ24KR35S",
        "createUserName":"Christian Johnson",
        "lastModifiedTime":"2022-09-06T15:30:28.0000000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId":"XW92MXHDEB88",
        "lastModifiedUserName":"JEG_Automation AFService",
        "hidden":false,
        "reserved":false,
        "extension":{
           "type":"items:autodesk.bim360:File",
           "version":"1.0",
           "schema":{
              "href":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
           },
           "data":{
              "sourceFileName":"WT1-131-D0-A01.pdf"
           }
        }
     },
```

Comment: your response is cropped, i didn't get your question fully. are you saying your results are more than 200? are you getting next page link in that case?

Comment: have you checked pagination? https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/#pagination